# log4j to have date in the file appender path

Tags: java, date, logging, path, log4j

I am using `DailyRollingFileAppender`

```
<appender name="daotofile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File"   value="${log.dir}/DAOLOG.log" />
  <param name="DatePattern"   value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />          
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

which gives me `E:\log\DAOLOG.log.2014-03-05.`

Is it possible to put date in to log4j appender log path? so the output is `E:\log\2014-03-05\DAOLOG.log`

Answer (score 0):

Nice requirement, but I think its not possible through just configuration alone.

You might have to set the System.setProperty("folder","2014-03-05"); dynamically whenever needed. Which may be a pain.

I actually move all the log files every month to a new folder manually.